Mongo bulk deletion very slow, and use all IOPS
I have a collection with 150M records, and that collection is very heavy and has more than 23 indexes. Now I need to make a retention and delete 15M records, all the preparation is already done, and I have collected in a separate collection all the ids we need to delete. So now it simple as:

take a chunk of IDs to delete
run deleteMany to delete records with these IDs

All this runs as a corn job, it takes the first chunk, deletes it, and stops, and after some period it does it again.
So I started deletion every 4 minutes and tried to delete 10k records, it did not work well, The first cron run was fast, but in every next run delete query was crazy slow, 2 minutes, some times 5-8 minutes, and sometimes even failing with Failed to read 4 bytes: socket error or timeout. I tried different combinations:

5k chunks every 2 and 5 minutes
2k chunks every 2 and 5 minutes
1k chunks every 2 and 5 minutes

And the same, the first run fast, and all the next runs very slow.
Additionally IOPS on the instance is 100% and in general, all queries performance decreasing a lot. I have a master and 2 replicas.
Is there a way to make it better?

How are you getting the "chunk of IDs to delete"? Are these actual values for the _id field or something other field? When you say "every next run delete query was crazy slow" is that for the chunked ID finder or for the deletion? Are you running your chunk-finder on the primary?

so, I have another collection where Yes I hold _id fields we need to delete from the main collection, so I run deleteMay({"_id" : {"$in" : [list of ObjhectIds]}}). It's for deletion, to get the next chunk it's fast (a few ms), but actually deleteMany query is very slow

I think it is somehow related to the number of indexes, those are not TTL and replicas, I think each time we delete the record mongo needs to update all the indexes and all the replicas with their own indexes, no? But anyway it should not be so slow?

but in that case why the first deletion is fast, but all consecutive no, so I have a feeling that Mongo still doing something async after the deletion, so the next run is slow because IOPS is still in use. But I tried to run cron every 10 minutes and still the issue is there, and I can't run it once per hour, it'll delete 15M record forever

You could try dropping all the indexes (except the default on _id which can't be dropped) and then running the sequence again to see if that makes a notable difference. Also, I would increase chunk size to 100k and compare the second deletion time with the 1k chunk.

Also, since this is not about a specific programming problem, I would migrate this to dba.stackexchange.com.

well, dripping all indexes on  prod DB is not easy, only maybe if I can make a copy of the collection, drop indexes delete records and use that new collection and drop old one. If I just drop all indexes on prod collection it'll fuckup everything :)

Yeah, not on Prod of course. You'll need to use a lower-environment with an equivalent number of docs to test it. But if you find that it is due to indexes and not due to replication, then you'll probably need to temporarily drop indexes during this process. And 23 indexes does seem a bit excessive but that's a different topic and requires context. Is your deleteMany running with Write Concern w: majority (the default?)

Check replication status between batches.  MongoDB flow control will introduce delays into the write path if replication lag starts to increase, so making sure all of the secondary nodes are fully caught up before starting a batch may help with performance impact.
